# Images in Server not appearing in WordPress Media Library

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I was messing around with some SQL queries and I screwed something up; and since then, images that exist on the server of the website do not appear in the WordPress Media Library. It appears to be an issue with the `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` tables.

I think I got the database corrupted; although, when the images are accessed through `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/YEAR/MONTH/FILE_NAME`, the images are displayed and they also display fine on the homepage, but they are missing in the WordPress Media Library. Only newly uploaded images show up. I need to fix this quickly.

Any help would be appreciated a whole lot. Thanks.

Comment: *screwed something up*, huh?  Can you [edit] your question to be more specific?  Did you do an `UPDATE` operation? A `DELETE` operation?

Answer (score 1):

Items in the media library are represented by rows in `wp_posts`. They have `post_type = 'attachment'`. Did you DELETE some of those rows?

**Edit**: For an item to appear in WordPress's media library, it must *both* appear someplace in the `/uploads/YYYY/MM/` folder and in an `'attachment'` row in the `wp_posts` table. Each media library item has its own row in that table. It seems unlikely that *changing* `post_type` values in that table will restore your media library.  Unless they're still there and you somehow changed their `post_type` values when you were messing around. Unlikely.

Do you have a backup of your database? If so, restore it.  That is your best bet.

At any rate, **make a backup before you start trying to repair this problem.** Then make regular backups. It's not hard, and it will save you untold grief in the future.

Do you have dozens of missing items? If so, download them from your WordPress file system with FTP, then re-upload them with the WordPress media library functionality, to re-create them.

**Edit** Don't delete them from your `uploads/YYYY/MM` folders; just re-upload them. They'll end up in two places in those folders, with the newer of the two corresponding to the newly created `'attachment'` row in `wp_posts`. Older posts should still render correctly, using the older image files in the folders.

If having some images show up twice in `uploads` is a problem, please see my question above about backups.

Or, try using the AddFromServer plugin to restore your missing items. https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/

Do you have hundreds, or more, of missing items? If so, you could be in a genuinely unpleasant situation.

Comment: Thanks,
In my database, `post_type` is either `post` or `revison`. How do I set it to `attachment`, and wold that help?

Also, I don't have a backup of the database. You also said that I should re-upload the images, but the posts contain images with `YEAR` and `MONTH` in the url, so the posts that contain those images might have the images broken. I'll check the AddFromServer plugin too.